# Find a MongoDB document based on element match of a specific subtype type

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the Mongo C# Driver version 2.2.3 connecting to a Mongo 3.0.6 server.

Given MongoDb Collection of the Person class (see below)  I would like to find the person with the email address of "not@home.com".  Somewhat naively  and I had hoped that something like tis would work:

```
var people = database.GetCollection<Person>("People");

var person = from p in people.AsQueryable()
where p.Addresses.OfType<EmailAddress>().Any(e=>e.MailTo == "not@home.com")
```

However at runtime, I receive a `NotSupportedException`.  The method OfType is not supported in the expression tree.

Is there a simple way to element match (with strong typing) a polymorphic array?

(here's the model)

```
class Person
{
    public Address[] Addresses {get;set;}
}
class Address
{
}
class Phone : Address
{
    public string Number {get;set;}
}
class Email : Address
{
    public string MailTo {get;set;}
}
```

the sample document I'm trying to find is:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d76465b27c42eb491aa2e7"),
        "Addresses" : [
                {
                        "_t" : "Email",
                        "MailTo" : "not@home.com"
                },
                {
                        "_t" : "Phone",
                        "Number" : "555-1234"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: what driver and db version?

Comment: @profesor79 I've updated the question.  Server ion 3.0.6, and C# driver 2.2.3

Comment: I was testing : var x = people.Where(z=>z.Addresses.OfType<Email>().Any(e => e.MailTo == "not@home.com")); without exception - could you be so kind and dump one object for reference?

Comment: now got same exception on mongo driver :(

Comment: that's a nice deadlock, Sir. cannot ask for field name as it is covered by child class and cannot project class type as driver cannot handle that...
created driver issue on MongoDb site https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi this is fixed now in 2.2.4
please see  [mongodb jira entry](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1589)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Although C# driver is not fully implemented and it lack a lot of features, but in my opinion issue is in your class structure.

e.g. a Person object will have addresses and address may be of type Phone or Email or even both. That's where driver is complaining as it can't comprehend what type of object there could be.

Since it's more dynamic in nature, so I'll recommend you to use BsonDocument type to query and than typecast to whatever object you want. Said that you have few options to get your result

**OPTION #1:**

If you execute following code:

```
var mailTo = "not@home.com";
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch("Addresses",
    Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("MailTo", mailTo));

var people = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("People");

var person  = people.FindSync(filter).ToList();
```

You'll get a record containing `not@hotme.com` in sub document.

**OPTION #2:**

If it's possible for you to alter model little bit, you can take full advantage of linq queries.

```
public class Person
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Address[] Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string MailTo { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}   

var mailTo = "not@home.com";
var filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.ElemMatch(e => e.Addresses, 
    address => address.MailTo == mailTo );

var people = database.GetCollection<Person>("People");
var person  = people.FindSync<Person>(filter).ToList();
```

Now person will hold one or more Person objects matching your criteria.